# Overwriting images when deploying using Spring

Tags: java, spring, image, hibernate, deployment

I have the following problem: I haven an application which uses SpringMVC and Hibernate, and when the user uploads an image it stores it in the /resources/img folder, but when I have to do another deploy I complile my source code into a war, and then I deploy it again, overwriting the image that the user has just upload becose the whole folder is in the war. I don't know how it works, but the problem is that the user lose every image that he has uploaded when I deploy the app again.

Does anyone know the best way to solve this? I know that save the image in the database is not a good practice, so I want to avoid that.

Thank you!

Comment: you should store the images outside the deployment folder. say mention a path in your config (application.properties) say `loc.images=/srv/app/images/`.. then use this location in your app to read and store images

Comment: I recommend storing your images somewhere other than the server on which the application is running. For example, AWS S3 has a very simple and easy to use API that you could quickly integrate with your application and use to persist your images off site. Using a offsite service will also be beneficial if your application ever has to scale horizontally by adding multiple web servers.